# Is it possible to launch a flow from an update trigger?

Tags: trigger, flow

I would like to launch a flow from an update trigger if a field on the object is set to a certain value. Is this possible? I understand that this is possible with the new Lightning capabilities, but can it be done through the apex code on the trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Flow triggers" won't be available until Winter 15. To use them, its required that no interaction on the part of a user be needed. For more on this, see the [Power of Flows: Advanced Workflow Techniques](https://developer.salesforce.com/en/events/webinars/power_of_flow) page which has videos from the webinars and links to other resources. Great series that I highly recommend.